How am I supposed to enter the a size-parameter to a colored plot_ly plot?
In plotly::plot_ly, it is possible to adjust size for each point and also to color points according to the category they belong to. Let me state how it is done:
library(plotly)
pd <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=1:4, color=c("a", "b", "a", "b"), size=5*(1:4))

plot_ly(pd, x=~x, y=~y, color=~color)
plot_ly(pd, x=~x, y=~y, marker = list(size=~size))
plot_ly(pd, x=~x, y=~y, color=~color, marker = list(size=~size))

You get the following results:



You see that seperately they work fine but combined the plotted result is wrong (the size is not correct). You can also see that the points in the legend are not the same size. Is there a way to solve these problems?
I believe that the wrong plotting is a bug, am I correct?

You can use the size argument without wrapped in the marker option like this:
library(plotly)
pd <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=1:4, color=c("a", "b", "a", "b"), size=5*(1:4))

plot_ly(pd, x=~x, y=~y, color=~color, size = ~size)


Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Do you have any idea why my approach does not work but seems to be suggested everywhere despite not working correctly?

Might also be useful to set a marker, i.e., marker=list(sizemode="diameter", sizeref=1), to be better able to adjust the relative sizes of the circles.
